# LinkedList - AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute next

Tags: python, linked-list

Trying to find a loop in a linked list results in:

```
AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute next
```

in the line

```
p = head.next
```

**Question:** why is this happening?

Description:
Given a linked list, determine if it has a cycle in it.

To represent a cycle in the given linked list, we use an integer `pos` which represents the position `(0-indexed)` in the linked list where tail connects to. If `pos` is `-1`, then there is no cycle in the linked list.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode(object):
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def hasCycle(self, head, pos):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :type pos: int
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if pos == -1:
            return False
        p = head
        while True:
            head = head.next
            p = head.next
            if head == p:
                return True
```

Comment: ```def hasCycle(self, head, pos):
     
        if pos == -1:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```
This question on leetcode is kind of wrong. The above code can get you the results. The question has been changed recently

Comment: "Question: why is this happening?"  Because `head` is `None` at some point.  Step through your code with a debugger, and put a breakpoint at the line in question, `p = head.next`.  Figure out when `head` is `None` and then figure out why it's `None` in those cases, then figure out how to fix it.